# Need help understanding an author's argument against a piece of code

Tags: java, exception

I am learning Java from *Java: Just in Time, John Latham*. I have a bit of confusion.

We have a program which takes current age from command line argument and compute age next year.

```
public class AgeNextYear
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int ageNow = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int ageNextYear = ageNow + 1;

    System.out.println("Your age now is " + ageNow);
    System.out.println("Your age next year will be " + ageNextYear);
  } // main
} // class AgeNextYear
```

There are two ways that the user can make this program fail. First, they might run it without
a command line argument, and so it will have a problem when trying to access args[0].
Second, they may supply an argument which is not the string representation of a whole number and so the Integer.parseInt() method will not be able to
interpret the value as an int. 
And then, in order to avoid the two possible exceptions in this code, we could add some code to the AgeNextYear program which checks the validity of the user’s input. Then code is

```
 public class AgeNextYear
 {
  // Return true if and only if given string is all digits and non empty.
  private static boolean isNonEmptyDigits(String shouldBeDigits)
  {
    boolean okaySoFar = shouldBeDigits.length() != 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(okaySoFar && index < shouldBeDigits.length())
    {
      okaySoFar = Character.isDigit(shouldBeDigits.charAt(index));
      index ++;
    } // while
    return okaySoFar;
  } // isNonEmptyDigits


  // Check argument and compute result or report error.
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    if(args.length > 0 && isNonEmptyDigits(args[0]))
    {
      int ageNow = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int ageNextYear = ageNow + 1;

      System.out.println("Your age now is " + ageNow);
      System.out.println("Your age next year will be " + ageNextYear);
    } // if
    else
      System.out.println("Please supply your age, as whole number.");
  } // main

} // class AgeNextYear
```

Then, writer of the book says that,

> Whilst it is true that we have made the program robust against
>   exceptions, we should not be satisfied with this approach. First, it
>   was rather a lot of work – the program has doubled in size.  [--
>   Second, the checks that our new parts of the code make are also being
>   made by the parts of the program that caused the exceptions in the
>   first place. That is, the implementation of args[0] in an expression
>   contains a check that the length of args is at least one, otherwise it
>   will create an Exception. Also, the code inside Integer.parseInt() is
>   surely checking that each character of the argument is a digit. --]

I dont understand what he means in the brackets [--  --].

Comment: I don't think it's something meaningful

Comment: It sounds like the author is trying to convey that when the code runs, it checks to see if `args[0]` is valid, and if it isn't it will throw an exception.  Then instead of using an if statement to check, `if(args.length > 0)`, one could use a try/catch block instead

Comment: What are you actually asking for?  Is this a language issue with understanding the translated words?  Are there some technical references you don't get?  Or do you not understand the entirety, e.g. you thought it worked differently, so you want to know why the author makes some specific assertion?

Comment: It is saying that the `isNonEmptyDigits` method does the same thing that `Interger.parseInt()` does, only that you are manually doing it. A quick solution to this would be to just wrap the `Interger.parseInt()` inside a try-catch.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, this was a language issue, you really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

One of the hallmarks of bad code is there's a lot of it. The reason "it was a lot of work" is because the author of the book is a bad programmer.

Here's how a good programmer might write code that does the exact same thing, but in less code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if (args.length == 0 || !args[0].matches("\\d{1,3}")) // age must be in range 0-999
       System.out.println("Please supply your age, as whole number.");
   else
       System.out.println("Your age now is " + args[0] + "\nYour age next year will be " + (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + 1));
}
```

That's the entire program btw.

Notice how you don't need the `ageNow` or `ageNextYear` variables at all, and the `String.matches()` method is used to check if the string is made only of digits.

It should be noted that "checking if the string is only digits" does *not* protect against exceptions when calling `Integer.parseInt()` - if you pass it a number greater than `2147483647` (ie [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)) it will explode.

If you want proper protection, catch the expected exceptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Your age now is " + args[0] + "\nYour age next year will be " + (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + 1));
    } catch (NumberFormatException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Please supply your age, as whole number.");
    }          
}
```

which is totally robust and even less code again.

Comment: And it will successfully fail on input like `4000000000`, why not catch both ArrayIndexOutOfBounds and NumberFormat exceptions instead? And it will be the same amount of code in java 7, but with much easier code.

Comment: Well, the author does say *we should not be satisfied with this approach* so presumably they go on to show what the code should look like.

Comment: @user3707125 You caught me mid-stride - I was getting there. :)

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, yes, as BSMP says, author  will show optional way to catch exceptions in next section, this part is only preparation part. Also in this part, author said about exception when we enter number which is out of int range.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the book a little more clearly.

> the implementation of `args[0]` in an expression contains a check that the length of args is at least one, otherwise it will create an Exception

referring to:

```
if(args.length > 0 && isNonEmptyDigits(args[0])) //the expression
    {
```

> contains a check that the length of args is at least one

```
if (args.length > 0
```

> otherwise it will create an Exception

without the check for `> 0`, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would happen if there were no argument input.

---

Presumably, he will next go for an improved `try, catch` approach, which is how `Exceptions` are usually handled (*as illustrated by the other answer here*)